# How to specify generic type using generic in function argument

Tags: typescript, flowtype, typescript-generics

I wanna add typing for the `identity` function which takes in a generic type but Flow throws an error. How can I type this?

```js
type ContextValue<
  Value,
> = $ReadOnly<{
  value: Value,
  processValue: Value => Value,
}>;

function process<ContextValue<Value>>(valueObject: ContextValue<Value>): Value {
  return valueObject.processValue(valueObject.value);
}

const value: ContextValue<number> = process({value: 1, processValue: (a) => a + a});
```

[Try it on Flow playground](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2BAHsAagQwDYFcIA8AUFFFnhADREB8UAvFACQBKEmAJgPILYgEBvElABuOfAC4y4qsLAAnOAGMIAZ1XlJ0igzqbZAXxoBuIkQBmuBEuABLRFAXK1qgvCSoMMgvpo0AFGIUXABGAFYQNlLuyGj6PjI0AJRS+lBCpKTyEMC48giiMqERNgB0Tirq+oFF4ZHApUH4SaYGZkqIqsCFFNGIsV4UBAi4ALYhEPJ0jLYcEEi2oP4CTRBSAIyUjoqVGjJS-phJulCYUADUpwYtREA)

TypeScript answers are welcome too.

Comment: `identity` is the first example given [in the TypeScript handbook on Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#hello-world-of-generics). It's just a `<T> id(x:T): T` - takes a type returns the same type. I'm not sure what your identity function is doing, as it's not accepting any type.

Comment: [this](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2BAHsAagQwDYFcIA8AUFFFnhADREB8UAvFACQBKEmAJgPILYgEBvElABuOfAC4y4qsM4dyk6RQZ1FsgL40A3ESIAzXAgDGwAJaIoZjhCRnQBACo0AFGIpTHASk9QhpUgAnCGBcQIRRGV0NPWNEAGdgSI9YRGQ0dQIEXABbACMIQLpGa1tzUBcBdyUARkooeXUpF0wvVQaoAGoGjS9tIA) is how I'd expect an identity function to look like.

Comment: Thanks but I used identity as it was easy to write types for. Have edited the example to be a non-identity function to demonstrate that I need to know the types of the parameter.

Comment: Then you just need `process<Value>` where `Value` becomes your generic type argument. [Example](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2BAHsAagQwDYFcIA8AUFFFnhADREB8UAvFACQBKEmAJgPILYgEBvElABuOfAC4y4qsLAAnOAGMIAZ1XlJ0igzqbZAXxoBuIkQBmuBEuABLRFAXK1qgvpoAKMRS4AjAFYQNlLwSKgYMm4yNACUUvpQQqSk8hDAuPIIojJ+gTYAdE4q6vpeOQFBwPne+DGmBmZKiKrA2RRSCLgAtr4Q8gyOisWqHgI1EFIAjJSDziUyUh6YMbpQmFAA1GsGdUA).